# Laravel 5.2: Retrieving list of unique values in a many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have a pension type:

```
class Type extends Base
{
    use RecordStatusActiveTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'pn_pension_type';

    /**
     * The actual primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'pension_type_id';

    // Belongs To -----
    public function pensionClass() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Control\PensionClass', 'pension_class_id');
    }

    // Belongs To Many -----
    public function qualifiers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Pension\Qualifier', 'pn_pension_type_qualifier', 'type_id', 'qualifier_id');
    }
}
```

And a pension Qualifier:

```
class Qualifier extends Base
{
    use RecordStatusActiveTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'pn_pension_qualifier';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'rules' => 'array',
    ];

    // Belongs To Many -----
    public function types()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Pension\Type', 'pn_pension_type_qualifier', 'qualifier_id', 'type_id');
    }
}
```

They have a many to many relationship with a table in between as normal. I would like to grab a set of pension types and find the unique Qualifiers between all of them. I COULD just foreach through each of their qualifiers and end up with a list of unique qualifiers but I was wondering if their was an "Eloquent" way.

Comment: Did you try something like `Qualifiers::whereHas('pensions', function($query) use ($pensionIds) { $query->whereIn('id', $pensionIds); })->distinct()->get();` ? Or do you need the unique's loaded as a relation?

Comment: hrmmm i see where your going with that...let me try it out and see if thats what im looking for

Comment: PERFECT...please list as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `whereHas` will allow you to restrict the results based on the relation. In regards to what you want, you'd want to query from your Qualifiers like so.

```
Qualifiers::whereHas('pensions', function($query) use ($pensionIds) { 
    $query->whereIn('id', $pensionIds); 
})->distinct()->get();
```

Adding on `->distinct()` will then get you the unique entries.